# How to display a result in a label when I click onto a button?

Tags: c#

On my GUI (Graphical User Interface), I have a button named Enter and a label.
When I click `Enter`, I want my result to be shown in the label.  How do I do that?

Comment: WPF, WinForms, WebForms or ASP.NET MVC (or something else)?

Comment: I think it kind of trolling. Sorry.

Comment: It is always good to give details on which technology you are working on.

Answer (score 4):

For windows forms use the .Text property on the label:

```
 private void btnEnter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int themeaningoflifeuniverseandeverything = 420 / 10;
        lblResult.Text = themeaningoflifeuniverseandeverything.ToString();
    }
```

See exampe: [ButtonEvent.zip](http://aconsulting.se/sandbox/ButtonEvent.zip)

Comment: Sooo heavy variable name!! :D Also pleased to know that `themeaningoflifeuniverseandeverything ` is of type `int` ! cheers.

Comment: Sorry, had to put in a reference to hitchhiker's guide to the galaxy :) Please try googles calculator: http://www.google.se/search?hl=sv&rlz=1C1GGLS_enSE348SE348&q=the+answer+to+life+the+universe+and+everything&btnG=S%C3%B6k&meta=&aq=1&oq=the+answer

Comment: Your reputation + No of badges = themeaningoflifeuniverseandeverything :D cool best of luck man!! (+1)

Answer (score 2):

Double click on the button in the designer.  This should create you a handler function for the buttons click event, something like this:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
```

then in the function add the code to set the text of the lable:

```
lable.Text = myResult;
```

you should end up with something like this:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    lable.Text = myResult;
    }
```

As you said you have an int which is a percentage, and you have the value 0, I suspect that you are having problems getting the percentage not writing the value to the lable.  so you might want to [look at this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043164/why-does-decimal-divideint-int-work-but-not-int-int) as I suspect that you have something like:

```
int valuea;
int valueb;
int result= valuea/valueb*100;
```

in this example if valuea=45 and valueb=100 the value of result will be 0, not 45.

Comment: we need some more information, like what is the type of your result?  What do you expect it to put in the lable?

Comment: and what is the value of the percentage?  If you tooltip it what is the value in the tooltip?  You could also try doing myResult.ToString("P") to display as a percentage;

Answer (score 1):

```
    int result = 0; // declare a private variable to hold the result

    // Event handler for Click of Enter button
    private void Enter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        result = Add(10,20);  // set result to result of some function like Add

        label.Text = result.ToString();
    }

    private int Add(int a, int b)
    {
        return a + b;
    }
```

NOTE: I assume you are a beginner working with Winforms.

Answer (score 0):

In winforms or webforms:

```
label.Text = Enter.Text;
```

Answer (score 0):

Double click on button to generate event and write following code

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lable1.Text = ur result; //result must be in string format otherwise convert it to string
}
```