# multiplying a decimal by a floating point number

Tags: c#

Im trying to get 75% of the CTotal but as it is a decimal number it is rounding 0.75 to 0, does anyone know of a work around

```
        decimal refundtot = order.CTotal;
                //change it as it is making it = 0 


                refundtot = (75 / 100) * refundtot;
                refund.RefundTotal = refundtot;
```

Comment: Check this out : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043164/why-does-decimal-divideint-int-work-but-not-int-int

Comment: Did you solve your issue ?

Comment: @BobSwager yes thanks

Comment: Please mark my answer :))

Answer (score 1):

You should use one decimal number when you dividing numbers.

Your code should look like this :

```
efundtot = ((decimal)75 / 100) * refundtot;
```